# Testing if single features have predictive power alone

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, feature-selection, accuracy

I am working on a classification task where the target variable is binary. The feature space is huge (about 280 features) and I am almost certain that some of them are completely irrelevant for  classification.

Now, I am thinking about training one neural network for each feature. If the cross validation accuracy for a certain feature is above 50% I suggest the feature provides some important information. If it is at 50% or below it is basically not providing any important information as the result is not better than assigning classes randomly.

However, it came to my mind that **it might be possible that one feature does a bad job at classification on its own but is very important for the accuracy in combination with other features. Is this possible?**

So for instance: Feature 1 on its own provides 49.98% accuracy, Feature 2 on its own provides 64% accuracy **but** Feature 1 & Feature 2 together provide 74% accuracy. Is this possible?

Comment: I don’t have an example right now, but each feature can be totally independent of the outcome while being highly predictive when they are used together (particularly when you allow for all of the nonlinear combinations that a neural network will provide). From probability theory, a random variable $Y$ can be independent of $X_1$ without $Y$ being independent of $X_1\vert X_2$. // [The usual caveats about using “accuracy” as your measure of performance…](https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/)

Comment: See [Identifying features using two-sample t-test - resulting in over-fitting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199192/identifying-features-using-two-sample-t-test-resulting-in-over-fitting/199195#199195) for an example where your approach do not work!   Many similar posts ...

Comment: Maybe the most common example of @Dave's phenomenon (in ML circles anyway) is an XOR relationship: two bernoulli variables $x_1, x_2$ with $y=\operatorname{XOR}(x_1, x_2)$; on their own $x_1, x_2$ can't do better than random guessing, but together in a neural network you can get (near-)perfect classification.

Comment: Oh, that's brought up in @kjetilbhalvorsen's linked answer.

Comment: @Ben Reiniger: But some more substantive examples would be good: 1) Many people think salt in cooking makes the food better, but salt **alone**? 2) Catalysts in chemical reactions: Only the catalyst is of little use!

Comment: Read about “conflation”

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, simulated in `R`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2021)
N <- 1000
a <- -2
b <- 2
x <- runif(N, a, b)
g <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
y <- x - 2*x*g + rnorm(N, 0, 0.1)
d <- data.frame(x = x, g = as.factor(g), y = y)
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, col = g)) + 
    geom_point() +
    theme_bw()
Lx <- lm(y ~ x)
Lg <- lm(y ~ g)
L <- lm(y ~ x*g)
summary(Lx)$r.squared # = 0.000466123448518558, so basically  
                      # no predictive ability
summary(Lg)$r.squared # = 0.000428737021642939, so basically 
                      # no predictive ability
summary(L)$r.squared # = 0.992562429058087, so outstanding 
                     # predictive ability
```

Here, the `x` and `g` alone are awful predictors. However, using both together creates an excellent predictor. While, yes, I did have to engineer the interaction term, the question concerns a neural network, which would be able to figure out (or at least approximate) such a feature.

Interestingly, this example does not even feature much correlation between `x` and `g`.